# Alternative way of using System.IO.File.OpenWrite() in Using(Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("D:\sample.svg"))

Tags: c#, filestream

```
using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("D:\sample.svg"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = SvgStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

I have this code for converting a PPT to SVG. SvgStream contains the PPT Slides. I don't want to store the converted SVG file on a physical path like D:\sample.svg. Is it possible to store it on an object that is not a physical path?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to store it on an object that is not a physical path?

Sure. Create a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream` if you want to stream into memory rather than the file system.

And while I'm here: you might want to use the `CopyTo` method rather than this tedious business of buffering it over one page at a time.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean? Can I see it through code? Thanks again!

Comment: You can see the code by **reading the documentation for MemoryStream and the CopyTo method**. You can find the documentation by typing those words into any search engine. StackOverflow is for providing you help, not doing the work for you. If after reading the documentation and trying to write your program you are still having difficulty, ask a new question.

Comment: That's not my intention. I know how to use the CopyTo Method. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I saved it to a string:

```
SvgStream = new MemoryStream();
sld.WriteAsSvg(SvgStream);
SvgStream.Position = 0;
string[] svgArray = new string[MAX];

//instead of using(var  fileStream = File.IO.......
//I came up with this:
var sr = new StreamReader(SvgStream);
svgArray[i] = sr.ReadToEnd();
```